# error in my quotes Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string

Tags: javascript, jquery

in my console show me the next error:

*Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string*

if because my quotes?

```
    $("<tr onclick=post'('Sol/data.php',{case:" + data.ID + " });' >").html(

        "<td align='center'><h4>" + data.timeID                + "</h4></td>"

     ).appendTo('#info');
```

Comment: You are putting a `non-selector string` where a jQuery **selector** goes. `$("tr");` maybe? https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp

Comment: @JustinJmnz - jQuery selectors *are* strings. OP, this method is brutally unclear. Can you supply us with your *intended* HTML and we can show you a cleaner way of achieving the desired output? I'd assume your error is somewhere in your `onclick` being that it's never actually opened, followed by a mess of single-quotes that are seemingly unmatched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `post` is a JS function similar to this...

```
function post(url, obj) { ... }
```

You would likely benefit from using event handlers. The code below accomplishes the exact same thing and is much cleaner/more readable.

```
$("<tr />")
    .html("<td style='text-align: center;'><h4>"+data.timeID+"</h4></td>")
    .click(function() { post("Sol/data.php", {case: data.ID}); })
    .appendTo("#info");
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you.  Your quotes were off.

```
$("<tr onclick=post('Sol/data.php',{case:\"" + data.ID + "\"});>").html(
     "<td align='center'><h4>" + data.timeID + "</h4></td>"
 ).appendTo('#info');
```

[jsFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/8yfzzsew/)